# Adding another column to an existing table with JOIN, also using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, join

Okay so I this have this query and it works works:

```
SELECT games.week, local_team, games.local_goals, visitor_team, games.visitor_goals, winner1
FROM games
JOIN (SELECT local_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS local_team ON games.team_number_loc = local_team.team_number
JOIN (SELECT visitor_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS visitor_team ON games.team_number_vis = visitor_team.team_number
JOIN (
SELECT CASE
WHEN games.local_goals < games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_vis
WHEN games.local_goals > games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_loc
WHEN games.local_goals = games.visitor_goals
THEN null
END AS winner1,
game_number
FROM games)
AS winner1 ON games.game_number = winner1.game_number
```

But then I need to add a column for the name of the team who won the game, I was thinking something like this should do it:

```
SELECT games.week, local_team, games.local_goals, visitor_team, games.visitor_goals, winner1, winner2
FROM games
JOIN (SELECT local_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS local_team ON games.team_number_loc = local_team.team_number
JOIN (SELECT visitor_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS visitor_team ON games.team_number_vis = visitor_team.team_number
JOIN (
SELECT CASE
WHEN games.local_goals < games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_vis
WHEN games.local_goals > games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_loc
WHEN games.local_goals = games.visitor_goals
THEN null
END AS winner1,
game_number
FROM games)
AS winner1 ON games.game_number = winner1.game_number
JOIN
(SELECT CASE
WHEN winner1 = teams.team_number
THEN teams.team_name
WHEN winner1 is null
THEN 'no winner'
END AS winner2,
teams.team_number
FROM teams) AS winner2 ON winner2.team_number = winner1
```

But when I try that I get this errors:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 153
Invalid column name 'winner1'.

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 155
Invalid column name 'winner1'.

The output I'm hoping for is the exact same as the other bit of code, just with an added column for the name of the winning team.

Comment: Is `game_number` the PK of table `games`?

Comment: It's not, I just added it so I could make the first query work

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a calculated column inside a other sub-query what you are trying to do in last sub query.

you can try following query:-

```
SELECT games.week, local_team, games.local_goals, visitor_team, games.visitor_goals, winner1, winner2 = ISNULL(T.team_name, 'No Winner')
FROM games
JOIN (SELECT local_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS local_team ON games.team_number_loc = local_team.team_number
JOIN (SELECT visitor_team = teams.team_name, team_number FROM teams) AS visitor_team ON games.team_number_vis = visitor_team.team_number
JOIN (
SELECT CASE
WHEN games.local_goals < games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_vis
WHEN games.local_goals > games.visitor_goals
THEN games.team_number_loc
WHEN games.local_goals = games.visitor_goals
THEN null
END AS winner1,
game_number
FROM games)
AS winner1 ON games.game_number = winner1.game_number
LEFT JOIN
teams T ON T.team_number = winner1.winner1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that gives me exactly the out put I was hoping for!